# How to recover a table in SQLEXPRESS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm new to the sql scene and I made a mistake as expected.

[image]

I'm running a private server for a video game, and when I tried to activate/deactivate certain zones I accidentally put 0 as the zone's name. Now the problem is, I can't change it back due to an error that says:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
---------------------------
No row was updated.

The data in row 42 was not committed.
Error Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.
Error Message: The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(3 rows).

Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).
```

Comment: what is the table structure?

Comment: @PatrikPulai first of all, you have to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/Tour) to read more about the websites rules: *asking good questions, answering, accepting answers ...* and to get your first *"informed"* badge

Comment: You see this message because your table has no primary key.

Pretty much every table should have a primary key.  If you add an `IDENTITY` column to the table and make it the primary key it should then allow you to edit the rows that are duplicated. Or just select all 3 of the duplicates - delete them, then add them back correctly. Then add an appropriate primary key.

Answer (score 2):

**If you don't know the values then:**

If there is no triggers that audit this database, you can use a third-party tools to read the latest changes made on a database, based on the database log file. But make sure that the Log file is not shrinked.

You can use a tool trial like [ApexSQL Log](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) to get the past values.

If is doesn't work, then your data is lost. You have to get an older copy of the database

---

**If you know the values that you have changed:**

You have to add an identity column to the tables, changes the values back, and then remove it again. because like @MartinSmith commented the error you are receiving is because there is no primary key found in the table and you have many duplicated rows

Use the following sql command to add identity column

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Comment: @patrikpulai why not reading the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) until now?? getting the informed badge will make people helps you more

Comment: @patrikpulai did you know the values that you have changed?? if yes then you have to add an identity column to the table, changes the values back, and remove it again